# Keep margins of divs in a column with a floated bottom image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two columns 41% and 59% of the total screen width each. The height of the columns is 1102px.

In the first column I have 4 divs. The first one is for the navigation and it can be maximum 60px. The second one is for a logo I am using. The third one is for text and the fourth one is the trickiest one. I am using an image which does not have the same size and ratio. I want the image to get the 100% of the width.

My challenge is to get the height of the first image and the text divs to be dynamic depending on the heigh of the bottom image in the first column. For example, the margins are really big when the screen size is big :

[image]

```css
body{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.wrapper{
  background-color: #484848;
}

#col1{
  float:left;
  width:41%;
  height: 1102px;
  background-color: #E90649;
  position: relative;
}

img#productImg{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;

}
img#product{
  max-width:100%;

}
#col2{
  float: left;
  width:59%;
  height: 1102px;
  background-color: #124;  
}


div #centerText{
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:455px;
}

#productLogo{
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 70%;
}

.list {
  padding-right: 14px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline; 
    padding-left: 4px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

div.nav{
  padding-top: 3%;
  height:24px;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

#productImg img{
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="col1">
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<img id="productLogo" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a"/>
<div id="centerText">
<h1>#############</h1>
<p2>#############</p2>
<h3>#############</h3>
</div>
<div id="productImg"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" /></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="col2">aaaaaaaaa</div>
</body>
 </html>
```

I used the @media screen-size feature but still I am not happy with the results as I have to put many lines in the CSS. Ideally, the part with the first logo (stackoverflow) and the text will be vertically aligned to center and the `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` will have the same value (percentage). The height of this div will depend on the height of the bottom image (JS parsing possible here?) and thus the text can be dynamic using the `vw` or `vh` in the CSS.

Is there an easier way to align the divs in the column and keep everything without breaking (that was the initial problem)?